# Does "if at all" mean "if applicable" in this context?

Tags: meaning

> Tell us how often, **if at all**, you buy these items.

I searched what "if at all" means, but couldn't find the exact meaning that fits in this context. Does "if at all" mean "if applicable"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If applicable** is a good guess, but it's really closer to meaning **if ever.** The definition of ["at all"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/at%20all) is "in any way" or "to any extent."

How often do you buy these items,

> if you ever buy them?
>
> if you buy them at all?

Answer (score 0):

"If at all" means nothing. It is a short form for:

> Tell us how often you buy these items, **if** (you buy them) **at all**.

with the meaning:

> Tell us how often you buy these items, **if you ever buy them**.